# Issue with unix_timestamp

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have to populate a field as 9999-12-31 for that I am using the below statement. 
But when I check in for result it's giving 9998-12-27 00:00:00

`Select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('9999-12-31','YYYY-MM-DD'))`

Result: 9998-12-27 00:00:00

Comment: So you are now aware that *"Unix timestamp in seconds since 1970-01-01, stored as 32-bit Integer"* was never meant to cover year 9999. Great. Do you have a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use it like this:

```
Select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('9999-12-31','yyyy-MM-dd'));
```